# What is the oligomeric state of Leptospira LipL32 protein?

Tags: proteins, protein-structure, pdb, xray-crystallography

Does anyone know the oligomeric state of the mature and functional lipoprotein lipL32 in Leptospira?

It's an outer membrane-bound protein. In its mature state, the signal peptide (residues 1-20) is removed, and the cysteine (resid 21) reacts and binds with the head group of a lipid. I've looked through many articles, from x-ray to western blots, and although I understand its structure in terms of the single protein, the results from the x-ray crystal data (as per the protein data bank) are my cause for confusion.

[These are the results from LipL32 in the PDB](https://www.rcsb.org/search?request=%7B%22query%22%3A%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22group%22%2C%22nodes%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22terminal%22%2C%22service%22%3A%22text%22%2C%22parameters%22%3A%7B%22attribute%22%3A%22rcsb_uniprot_protein.name.value%22%2C%22operator%22%3A%22contains_phrase%22%2C%22value%22%3A%22LipL32%22%7D%7D%5D%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%7D%5D%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%2C%22label%22%3A%22text%22%7D%5D%2C%22logical_operator%22%3A%22and%22%7D%2C%22return_type%22%3A%22entry%22%2C%22request_options%22%3A%7B%22paginate%22%3A%7B%22start%22%3A0%2C%22rows%22%3A25%7D%2C%22results_content_type%22%3A%5B%22experimental%22%5D%2C%22sort%22%3A%5B%7B%22sort_by%22%3A%22score%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22desc%22%7D%5D%2C%22scoring_strategy%22%3A%22combined%22%7D%2C%22request_info%22%3A%7B%22query_id%22%3A%22de7f63af74c41a022aebf9ca339a35de%22%7D%7D). Three different structures, a multi-mer, and two different dimers.

Are these different geometries the result of the experiment, or is the protein's quaternary structure as one would expect in the organism?

Comment: If you are going to reference an outside resource, please provide the actual URL so people can see exactly where it goes. Do not use URL shorteners.

Comment: @MattDMo done - enjoy.

Comment: @AnthonyNash what MattDMo was referring to was to not use 3rd party shorteners. You can still shorten the link using standard formatting: [your text](URL) (or using the "add link" button in the formatting panel, that way the mouse over works and you can see the link is actually heading to RCSB, and not some dodgy website, which is obscured when you use the 3rd party sites.